# Ethers.js : "NONCE EXPIRED" when replacing transaction

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js

I am having this issue when I try to replace a transaction with the same nonce, and higher gas fees. For exemple I use a swap function from a DEX :

```
const tx1 = await contract.swapExactTokensForTokens( amountIn, amountOutMin, [TokenIn, TokenOut], AddressTo, deadline, {'gasPrice': gasPrice, 'gasLimit': gasLimit})
```

and then I try to replace the transaction with tx1's nonce :

```
const tx2 = await contract.swapExactTokensForTokens( amountIn, amountOutMin, [TokenIn, TokenOut], AddressTo, deadline, {'gasPrice': gasPrice+1*10**9, 'gasLimit': gasLimit, 'nonce': tx1.nonce})
```

After this, I instantly get the nonce_expired error. How can I proceed ?

Comment: This might be useful for you, https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/435

Answer (score 0):

probably, your slippage was too tight, try to set higher amountOutMin. For nonce, you should use web3.utils.toHex(txCount) where txCount is web3.eth.getTransactionCount

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In a wallet, each transaction has a different nonce to prevent replay attack.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84207/how-does-nonce-prevent-a-replay-attack-in-case-of-knowing-nonce-value

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33033993)